# C# - Visual studio - Publish prerequisites error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that uses .net 3.5 (created in C# - Visual Studio 2010). Application runs fine, but if I try to publish and set the prerequisites to use the same location as the application I get this:

Error   2   The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet.msp' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information. Aplication

I have the framework installed and also the kit but I guess I have to put some files somewhere... but I don't know where.

Can any1 help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/997550a7-1d5c-403b-9271-65d1daf67d83/):

> The reason is that we shipped the .NET
>   Frameworks 3.5 SP1 package as Homesite
>   Only, i.e. only supports "Install
>   Prerequisites from Component Vendor's
>   Website".  We did this to keep the
>   size of VS 2008 SP1 from being too
>   large.
>
> We did put info in the SP1 readme on
>   how to get the files put on your
>   machine to enable the samesite
>   scenario.  Look for "Enable Samesite".
>
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm